# Regularity of solution to an elliptic PDE

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $R$ be the shifted open unit cube 
\begin{equation}
\Big(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \Big)^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3,
\end{equation}
and let $k \in \mathbb{C}$ be a constant with $\textrm{Re}(k) <0$. 
Fix an $r \in (0, 1)$, and let $\psi \in H^1(R, \mathbb{C})$ be a function that is $1$-periodic in each argument, i.e., $\psi (x + e_i) = \psi(x)$ for all $i \in \{ 1,2,3\}$, where $e_i$ is the ith standard basis vector, and which satisfies
\begin{align}
- \Delta \psi &= k \psi & \textrm{ in } & R \setminus \overline{B_{r}(0)} \\
\psi &= 1 & \textrm{ in } & \overline{ B_{r}(0)}, 
\end{align}
where $B_{r}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is the open ball of radius $r$.

Using standard results from the regularity theory of elliptic equations, I can show that $\psi \in C^{\infty}(R \setminus B_{r}(0))$. In particular, $\psi \in C^0 (R)$.

> I would like to prove that $\psi$ is more regular (e.g, $\psi \in C^1(R)$).

By the very definition of $\psi$, we know that $\nabla \psi \equiv 0$ in the open ball $B_r(0)$. We also know that $\psi$ is smooth in $R \setminus \overline{B_r(0)}$. So, we are left to prove that $\nabla \psi = 0$ on $\partial B_r(0)$. However, I have no idea how to tackle this problem (in fact, I do not know if $\psi$ is continuously differentiable in $R$ at all).

I would be grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

generically $\psi \notin C^1$. You can already see that in one dimension: the solutions in 1d are exponential functions cut off at a certain height by a constant function (for $k$ real and negative).